# Exporting two services in Spring

Tags: java, spring, service, configuration

I have a problem in Spring such that I get the next error when I try to export two services from server to client:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Could not find RMI service [rmi://localhost:1099/ClientsService] in RMI registry; nested exception is java.rmi.NotBoundException: ClientsService
```

This is my Configuration in the server side:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientsServerConfig {
    @Bean
    RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter() {
        RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
        rmiServiceExporter.setServiceInterface(ClientService.class);
        rmiServiceExporter.setService(clientService());
        rmiServiceExporter.setServiceName("ClientsService");
        return rmiServiceExporter;
    }
    @Bean
    ClientService clientService() {
        return new ClientsServiceImpl(clientRepository());
    }
    @Bean
    RepositoryInterface<Long, Client> clientRepository() {
        return new ClientDbRepository();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class GunProviderServerConfig{
    @Bean
    RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter() {
        RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
        rmiServiceExporter.setServiceInterface(GunProviderService.class);
        rmiServiceExporter.setService(gunProviderService());
        rmiServiceExporter.setServiceName("GunProviderService");
        return rmiServiceExporter;
    }
    @Bean
    GunProviderService gunProviderService() {
        return new GunProviderServiceImpl(gunProviderRepository());
    }
    @Bean
    RepositoryInterface<Long, GunProvider> gunProviderRepository() {
        return new GunProviderDbRepository();
    }
}
```

and this is the configuration in the client side:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/ClientsService");
        rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(ClientService.class);
        return rmiProxyFactoryBean;
    }
    @Bean
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean2() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/GunProviderService");
        rmiProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(GunProviderService.class);
        return rmiProxyFactoryBean;
    }
```

And the error is caused I think because the application does not know what service to use when two are exported. If I comment "GunProviderServerConfig" and "rmiProxyFactoryBean2" such that I have only the ClientService, the app will work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue yesterday but it worked for me this morning. consider moving the two exporters to the same configuration class